# How can I select only characters from a string?

Tags: python-3.x

This is my array:

```
array([['Family one206(+33%)1,164(+179%)0418'],
       ['Family one206(+33%)1,164(+179%)0418'],
       ['Family Two(-67%)23(-47%)23'],
       ['Family Two(+56%)322(-0.6%)1080'],
       ['Family Two(+56%)322(-0.6%)1080'],
       ['Family Two(+56%)322(-0.6%)1080'],
       ['Family Two(+56%)322(-0.6%)1080'],
       ['Family Three5,250(+2.6%)36,410(-2.7%)260412'],
       ['Family Three5,250(+2.6%)36,410(-2.7%)260412'],
       ['Family Three5,250(+2.6%)36,410(-2.7%)260412'],
       ['Family Three5,250(+2.6%)36,410(-2.7%)260412'],
       ['Family Three5,250(+2.6%)36,410(-2.7%)260412'],
       ['Family Three5,250(+2.6%)36,410(-2.7%)260412'])
```

But i only want my array to looks like :

```
array([['Family one'],
       ['Family one'],
       ['Family Two'],
       ['Family Two'],
       ['Family Two'],
       ['Family Two'],
       ['Family Two'],
       ['Family Three'],
       ['Family Three'],
       ['Family Three'],
       ['Family Three'],
       ['Family Three'],
       ['Family Three']])
```

I am not sure how i can only select string from a mixed string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex:

```
import re

arr = np.array([['Family one206(+33%)1,164(+179%)0418'],
       ['Family one206(+33%)1,164(+179%)0418'],
       ['Family Two(-67%)23(-47%)23'],
       ['Family Two(+56%)322(-0.6%)1080'],
       ['Family Two(+56%)322(-0.6%)1080'],
       ['Family Two(+56%)322(-0.6%)1080'],
       ['Family Two(+56%)322(-0.6%)1080'],
       ['Family Three5,250(+2.6%)36,410(-2.7%)260412'],
       ['Family Three5,250(+2.6%)36,410(-2.7%)260412'],
       ['Family Three5,250(+2.6%)36,410(-2.7%)260412'],
       ['Family Three5,250(+2.6%)36,410(-2.7%)260412'],
       ['Family Three5,250(+2.6%)36,410(-2.7%)260412'],
       ['Family Three5,250(+2.6%)36,410(-2.7%)260412']])

new_array = np.array([re.findall('[A-Za-z\s]+', i) for i in arr.squeeze()])

>>> new_array
array([['Family one'],
       ['Family one'],
       ['Family Two'],
       ['Family Two'],
       ['Family Two'],
       ['Family Two'],
       ['Family Two'],
       ['Family Three'],
       ['Family Three'],
       ['Family Three'],
       ['Family Three'],
       ['Family Three'],
       ['Family Three']],
      dtype='<U12')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can decide to replace everything from where a non-word starts and the next is also a non word to the end with non-space
Let `a` be your array above, then we can do:

```
import re
s =  np.array([[re.sub(r"(?i)[^A-Z](?![A-Z]).*","",i)] for i in a.squeeze()])
s
array([['Family one'],
       ['Family one'],
       ['Family Two'],
       ['Family Two'],
       ['Family Two'],
       ['Family Two'],
       ['Family Two'],
       ['Family Three'],
       ['Family Three'],
       ['Family Three'],
       ['Family Three'],
       ['Family Three'],
       ['Family Three']], dtype='<U12')
```